# Could we help each other through chat in the next few days?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/36280/1100

@Caleb closed the above question. He may have had some legitimate reasons. I'd like my question to be reopened, but I'll leave that one for now.

In the meantime, I was wondering:

> Could we help each other through chat in the next few days?

Many Christian ministers will decline to address the [Charlie Hedbo shooting](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Hebdo_shooting) this weekend on the Sabbath in any meaningful way. To compensate, I was wondering if some of us who are trained in ministry (like fredsbend, Affable Geek, and @onlyheisgood.) could be available to answer any questions that people might have about the tragedy.

The fact is: This tragedy, like the [Boston Bombing](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Marathon_bombings), the [Sichuan Earthquake](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Sichuan_earthquake), and [9/11](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks) have shaken people to their core. People all over the world are questioning God, religion, etc. As a community of Christians, I think we should do what we can to help people with their faith.

Comment: I'm not sure I would be much help for people looking to strengthen their faith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to organize a chat event for this community. That sounds like a fine idea. I know other communities have them.

I have created the chatroom: [Charlie Hebdo Vigil](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20132/charlie-hebdo-vigil).

You and anyone else interested may go there to discuss the recent event and how it does or does not impact their faith.

Comment: Could you please create a "Charlie Hebdo Vigil" chat room ASAP? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JimG. I've created the room and made the first two relevant posts.